# Combining 3 columns into one in a access query

Tags: microsoft-access-2007

I have inserted a column into design view of my query.  How do I combine three separate columns into one.  I need to get the City, State and Zip into my new column?

Answer (score 1):

with the question i can only suggest this.

SELECT [Field1] & ", " & [Field2], " & [Field3]
FROM DesiredTable;

Comment: this solve your problem??? if yes, please Mark this question as answered. Just click on check image in the left of this post.